# Can't use .withdraw() from Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am doing my first programming class this semester and for our exam I am creating this very basic Lightroom clone.

I am using opencv for the image processing and Tkinter as GUI. Everything kind of works so far, but I am struggling to hide the main menu (Tkinter GUI) when the image is opened (OpenCV GUI).

I want to call the .withdraw method for the TKinter root window from the innit function of the image processing class. Image opens -> Menu hides. I think these pictures might help:

[Here the GUI initializes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZcKb.jpg)

```py
from tkinter import *
import Panels

def createpanels(amount=10):
    img1 = "thumbnail.jpg"
    for i in range(0, amount):
        Panel = (Panels.Panel("Image A", img1, i + 1, 5))
        button_edit = Button(window, text="Bild Bearbeiten", command=Panel.showpath)
        button_edit.grid(column=i + 1, row=6, pady = 10)



def hidegui():
    window.withdraw()

def showgui():
    window.deiconify()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = Tk()
    window.title("File Explorer")
    window.config(background="white")
    current_value = tk.DoubleVar()
    createpanels()
    button_exit = Button(window, text = "Exit", command = exit)

    button_exit.grid(column=11, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)

    window.mainloop()
```

[Here I am trying to call the withdraw method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJRlS.jpg)

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import TkinterGUI as gui
import Filter
import Goldencut as g
from PIL import Image
import Filter as f

class Image:

    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, path):

        self.path = path
        self.img = cv.imread(self.path)
        self.imgcopy = self.img.copy()
        self.gc = self.img.copy()

        cv.namedWindow("Image", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv.namedWindow("Controlls", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)

        gui.hidegui()
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I get this error message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mkHE.jpg)

I am pretty sure this is an absolute beginner mistake and easy to fix, but I just can't fix it myself. Any help very appreciated :)

Comment: Please paste your code as text rather than as an image

Comment: The formatting unfortunately does not work for me

Comment: I'm not sure if I've misunderstood your design, but it looks like you want to run the GUI from another file, so it would make sense to remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` from your GUI file. This would also resolve the `withdraw` error.

Comment: Please consider pasting the error log instead of uploading an image. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`window = Tk()` use outside of function like this
here is the complete code because you are calling an undefined class name

```
from tkinter import *
import Panels

window = Tk() # use here 

def createpanels(amount=10):
    img1 = "thumbnail.jpg"
    for i in range(0, amount):
        Panel = (Panels.Panel("Image A", img1, i + 1, 5))
        button_edit = Button(window, text="Bild Bearbeiten", command=Panel.showpath)
        button_edit.grid(column=i + 1, row=6, pady = 10)



def hidegui():
    window.withdraw()

def showgui():
    window.deiconify()



if __name__ == "__main__":

   
    window.title("File Explorer")
    window.config(background="white")
    current_value = tk.DoubleVar()
    createpanels()
    button_exit = Button(window, text = "Exit", command = exit)

    button_exit.grid(column=11, row=5, padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```